# T SQL Adress Table with the same Company need latest Contact

Tags: sql, select, join, outer-apply

i got an Address Table with Primary and Secondary Company locations, example:

## ADDRESSES:

```
 ID    CompanyName       AdressType    MainID    Location 

 1    ExampleCompany        H             0        Germany 

 2    ExampleCompany        N             1        Sweden
   
 3    ExampleCompany        N             1         Germany
```

and we got another Contacts Table including the latest Contact to each of the Company Locations

## Contacts

```
ID    SuperID    Datecreate    Notes

1       1        10.04.2018     XY

2       3        09.04.2018     YX

3       2        11.04.2018      XX
```

Now we want to select the latest Contact per Company and sort them so we got a list of all our customers that we did not contact in a long time.

i thought about something like this:

```
SELECT 
ADDRH.ID,
ADDRH.COMPANY1,
TOPCONT.ID,
TOPCONT.DATECREATE,
TOPCONT.NOTES0

FROM dbo.ADDRESSES ADDRH
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 ID, SUPERID, DATECREATE, CREATEDBY, NOTES0 FROM DBO.CONTACTS CONT WHERE ADDRH.ID = CONT.SUPERID ORDER BY DATECREATE DESC) TOPCONT
WHERE
TOPCONT.ID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY TOPCONT.DATECREATE
```

But this is still missing the fact that we got the same company multiple times in the addresses table. how can i create a list that got each company with the latest contact?

Thanks for your help

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to remove duplicates from address as well.  Because of the structure of your data, I think the best approach is to use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT ac.*
FROM (SELECT a.ID, a.COMPANY1, c.ID, c.DATECREATE, c.NOTES0,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.COMPANY1 ORDER BY c.DATECREATE DESC) as seqnum
      FROM dbo.ADDRESSES a JOIN
           DBO.CONTACTS c
           ON a.ID = c.SUPERID
      WHERE c.ID IS NOT NULL
     ) ac
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY c.DATECREATE;
```